# How to configure Heroku to receive webhooks from GitHub?

Tags: python, heroku, github-webhook

I am trying to create a **GitHub Webhook** that pings a *URL* whenever one of my repos is updated. I want to ping my application running on **Heroku**, but I am not sure how to setup Heroku to accept an external webhook.

I see that Heroku can create webhooks, but I don't see if Heroku can receive a payload from a  webhook.

Is this possible?

EDIT:
I should add, the idea would be when Heroku receives a response from the webhook, a command from the Heroku Scheduler add-on would run. So I guess the real question is if it's possible to have Heroku receive a webhook response and then run a Heroku Scheduler add-on command.

Comment: Well you'd just run arbitrary code on Heroku. Do you have an application to run?

Comment: @Chris I'm trying to have Heroku run a Heroku Scheduler add-on command whenever a webhook response is received.

Comment: That's not how it works. Heroku _Scheduler_, as its name suggests, runs a command on a _schedule_. If you want to respond to a request to a given path you should run an application that has an appropriate route and request handler. Heroku isn't Amazon Lambda. Use the right tool for the job.